# DNX core application version information

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx

In earlier .NET based applications I implemented a central method for returning application information, usually product name, version and legal copyright. This method was implemented via System.Reflection.Assembly or in newer applications via System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo. This allowed me keep the version number in a central place, namely the main assembly file, and edit it easily in Visual Studio project properties.

Now in DNX core all this doesn't seem to be available, neither System.Reflection nor System.Diagnostics.

How would you suggest to manage version information in a DNX core based ASP.NET 5 application in a platform neutral way?

Comment: The project.json file has a version number, name, description, copyright, authors etc. These are the same properties used to build a NuGet package. I believe you can read this file using ```Configuration.GetConfigurationSection```.

Comment: That sounds great. I hoped there would already be a standard way but, anyway, that seems to be easy and intuitve. Couldn't you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project.json file has a version number, name, description, copyright, authors etc. These are the same properties used to build a NuGet package. In fact, if you create a 'Class Library (Package)' project, you can compile it directly to a NuGet .nupkg file by checking the option in project properties.

I believe you can read this file using `Configuration.GetConfigurationSection`. `ApplicationSettings` is just a class with the properties from the project.json that you want to read.

```
var configurationSection = configuration.GetConfigurationSection(nameof(ApplicationSettings));
var applicationSettings = ConfigurationBinder.Bind<ApplicationSettings>(configurationSection);
```

Comment: My project.json does only contain a version number at the top, no copyright, author, productname etc.. Anyway, I was able to do what you suggest with my config.json file where I added all version information myself.

Comment: You can add those properties. They are not there by default. You should get intelli-sense for them but you need to use Beta 6 and above I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement something like dnx's `IRuntimeEnvironment`:

- [IRuntimeEnvironment](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/219871c6063d00f8297eeafe93266f1048f59a45/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Abstractions/IRuntimeEnvironment.cs#L37)
- [RuntimeEnvironment](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/219871c6063d00f8297eeafe93266f1048f59a45/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Host/RuntimeEnvironment.cs#L74-L90) (the implementation of `IRuntimeEnvironment`)

> Now in DNX core all this doesn't seem to be available, neither System.Reflection nor System.Diagnostics.

Not sure what you mean by that. `System.Reflection` and `System.Diagnostics` are available: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/219871c6063d00f8297eeafe93266f1048f59a45/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Host/project.json#L21-L23

If you cannot find a particular type, use the [PackageSearch](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) website to see in which NuGet package it is

Comment: Great, that also works. I was unclear about System.Reflection and System.Diagnostics. In older code I used for example System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly. For this Intellisense tells me it's not available in the core CLR.

Comment: Correct, `GetExecutingAssembly` is not available in CoreCLR